# Cambiar color a botones del toolbar Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, angular, fullcalendar

He intentado cambiar el color de la botonera como dice la documentación [Fullcalendar Customize CSS](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/css-customization) pero no me ha funcionado (he tratado las dos formas).

[image: necesito cambiar los botones azules a rojo o cualquier color]

Este es mi código hasta el momento, estoy trabajando con Angular 12 y fullcalendar v5:

```
    calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
        
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'title',
          right: 'today,prevYear,prev,next,nextYear'
        },
        height: 'auto',
      }
```

Comment: La unica forma que he visto es atravez de css, ya lo he hecho pero solo aplica cambios cuando publico en la web el proyecto

Comment: .fc-right .fc-prev-button, .fc-right .fc-next-button{
    background-color: #b1d583;
    background-image: none;
}

Comment: Entonces los cambios solo se ven afectados cuando se sube a producción?

Comment: En mi caso fue asi

Answer (score 0):

siempre puedes declarar clases sobre clases. recuerda que el compilador asigna la última clase encontrada, por tanto estos estilos deben estar debajo de los stylesheet del fullcalendar.

```
button.fc-dayGridMonth-button.fc-button.fc-button-primary {
    background-color: red !important;
    border-color: mediumvioletred;
}
```

Basta con usar el inspector de elementos, seleccionar el botón del fullcalendar y dar clic en "+" new style rule. El navegador te entrega la clase completa del elemento.

Comment: por el momento, lo intente poniendo la configuracion css del boton dentro del scss del componente pero no efectua ningun cambio